# A file activation error occurred. The physical file name 'N@filename 

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Below t-sql code compiles fine. But when I run it like
exec [SP_ATTACH_NW] N'C:\myfolder' I get

Msg 5105, Level 16, State 2, Procedure SP_ATTACH_NW, Line 14
A file activation error occurred. The physical file name 'N@mdfFileName' may be incorrect. Diagnose and correct additional errors, and retry the operation.

```
USE master

GO

SET ANSI_NULLS ON

GO

CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[SP_ATTACH_NW] (
    @DestFolder varchar(255)
)

AS

BEGIN

    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    Declare @mdfFileName varchar(255)
    Declare @ldfFileName varchar(255)

    set @mdfFileName = @DestFolder + '\northwnd.mdf'
    set @ldfFileName = @DestFolder + '\northwnd.ldf'

CREATE DATABASE [Northwind] ON 

( FILENAME = N@mdfFileName ),

( FILENAME = N@ldfFileName )

 FOR ATTACH


END
```

Pls advise. thanks

Comment: You can't just chuck parameters into the middle of TSQL statements and expect the parameter values to be substituted in. You can use dynamic SQL to do this. Seems an odd thing to do via a stored procedure anyway.

Comment: What is your usage for this? Why do you need a SP to create a DB?

Comment: ok. bgn below has answered my question. I needed to move a db to another drive so users who run out of space one one drive can run a little app to do this. Using sql dmo and c# I was able to detach, move mdf/ldf files but when attaching it failed due to folder permission issues on the new mdf/ldf folder location. Rather than mess with folder permissions I decided to do the attach via a sp.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't have variables in the filename arguments of [CREATE DATABASE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms176061.aspx) (MSDN doesn't show @vars in the syntax)

The code above is literally looking for the constant "N@mdfFileName" as a filename.

You'd need dynamic SQL to build a string in, say, @MyBuiltSQL then run `EXEC(@MyBuiltSQL)`

Note: The "N" prefix here would not make @mdfFileName nvarchar anyway